# Excel Numerical Precision Issue with COUNTIF: for few numerical values counting X as being larger than X itself

Tags: excel, precision, countif

While `COUNTIF()` for most numerical arguments rightly answers 0 when asked the triviality **how many values among `X` are larger than `X`** (i.e. `COUNTIF(X,">X")` yielding 0), **for some weird numerical values of `X`, `COUNTIF(X,">X")` yields 1, thus wrongly claiming `X` would be larger than `X`**.

Consider a constant value to be in Cell `A1` (the `X` above).

Consider Cell `A2` to count all values in `A1` only (i.e. Range `A1:A1`), which are larger than A1 itself:

`=COUNTIF(A1:A1,">"&A1)`

For "normal" (i.e. most) values in `A1`, this rightly yields 0.

For some specific values, call them "weird" values, I find it to return 1, however.

A way to create an example of such a weird number manually is:

`=564.777008837525+(564.777008837526-564.777008837525)/2` as value for `A1`

Use instead essentially nearly *any* other value for `A1`, and you find `COUNTIF` instead to work.

I reckon a bug related to numerical precision when calculating the `COUNTIF` result.

**Is there any genuine fix to this?** Or instead only workarounds?

Excel Version: Excel 2016

Note:

1. This is not related to the special case of `A1:A1` to be a 'collapsed' 1-cell-only range. Use larger ranges, filled with different values, and the same weird behavior obtains still.
2. Also, it does not matter whether the `criteria` parameter contains a reference to the "weird" value in the `range` parameter, or instead to an independent copy of that value in some other cell.
3. When you *manually* copy-paste the numeric form of the weird' *value* from the cell, and use the manually copied version, the problem disappears. I.e., when copying the value manually you seem to copy a slightly different numerical value; Excel does not seem to provide you the full precision of the number when giving you the numeric value in digits form; it seemingly errs instead on the side of showing less rather than more precision in the decimal number than what is truly stored in its binary format.
4. Other weird values leading to the same wrong counting behavior exist.

Comment: You can use `SUMPRODUCT`: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1>A1))`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen. Very useful, and _kind_ of works for me. Subtlety I have, is that some of the cells (say Y, value range) are formulas yielding "" instead of numbers. There, SUMPRODUCT gives a different answer than COUNTIF. I work around that using sth in the direction of IF(X<>"",SUMPRODUCT(--(Y:Y>X)) - COUNTIF(Y=""),0).